# findstr does not find "homepage":"http://www.google.com/"

Tags: batch-file, space, quotes

```
@echo off
cd /D "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
set ffile=%cd%

findstr /m ^"homepage^":^"http://www.google.com/^" "%ffile%\Secure Preferences"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Ok
)else (
    echo "Not Ok"

)
pause
```

`findstr` does not return anything when I search for `"homepage":"http://www.google.com/"`, but it works when I only search for "homepage" - why?

Comment: Well then your homepage is not set to http://www.google.com

Comment: In ^"homepage^":^"google.com^" return “homepage”:“google.com” but not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findstr` has "it's own" rules for escaping chars (well, it's REGEX rules) (see `findstr /?`):

```
findstr /r /c:\"homepage\":\"http://www\.google\.com/\" "%ffile%\Secure Preferences"
```

(the dot has to be escaped too, because it's REGEX code for "any char")

Comment: It's an extremely stripped down version of regex.

Comment: @SomethingDark the word you search for is "rudimentary" ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's it. It's like trying to use bash in OSX.

Comment: Not Work “homepage”:“http://www.google.com/”, but i used ^"homepage^":^"http://www.google.com/^" return “homepage”:“http://www.google.com/”

Comment: works fine for me. Can you give us the relevant line of your file, please? (please don't put it into a comment, edit your question)